# You're dealt n cards from a deck of $52$. P(n) is the probability of drawing at least $5$ hearts. What is the smallest value of n such that P(n)>0.5?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have already computed that in order to guarantee 5 hearts ($P(n) = 1$), $n = 44$ cards, because any less would leave a possibility for all $5$ hearts to not be there.

However, I don't know how to compute $n$ such that $P(n)$ is a specific probability other than $1$ or $0$.

The probability of getting $5$ hearts when drawing $5$ cards ($P(5)$) is $\frac{33}{66640}$. I believe that you need to add multiple of these together and/or multiply that by something, but I don't know. I could be/probably am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All $\binom{52}n$ selections of cards are equiprobable. Thus the probability of drawing exactly $k$ hearts is $\frac{\binom{13}k\binom{39}{n-k}}{\binom{52}n}$. The probability of drawing less than $5$ hearts is therefore

$$
1-P(n)=\sum_{k=0}^4\frac{\binom{13}k\binom{39}{n-k}}{\binom{52}n}\;.
$$

We can estimate that the number of cards needed for this to be  $\le\frac12$ should be around $\frac5{13}\cdot52=20$, and indeed

$$
1-P(18)=\frac{4833024}{9529015}\gt\frac12
$$

([Wolfram|Alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=sum%20of%20binom%20(13,k)%20*%20binom%20(39,18-k)%20%2F%20binom%20(52,18)%20for%20k%3D0..4)) and

$$
1-P(19)=\frac{41115765}{93384347}\lt\frac12
$$

([Wolfram|Alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=sum%20of%20binom%20(13,k)%20*%20binom%20(39,19-k)%20%2F%20binom%20(52,19)%20for%20k%3D0..4)).